# Java: Field Assignment after a label cannot compile

Tags: java, android

Please Help me i cannot resolve this jave code.

Compiler Errors are:

- Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token "String", AssignmentOperator expected after this token
- str4 cannot be resolved to a variable
- String cannot be resolved to a variable

Here is my code snippet:

```
public class CallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    public static String nameOrNumber = "";
    private Context context;
    boolean phonebook;
    boolean unknowncall;

    public CallListener(Context paramContext) {
        this.context = paramContext;`
    }

    public void onCallStateChanged(int paramInt, String paramString) {

        switch (((AudioManager) this.context.getSystemService("audio")).getRingerMode()) {
            default:
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
        }
        while (true) {
            SharedPreferences localSharedPreferences = this.context.getSharedPreferences("com.appbasic.callername", 0);
            this.unknowncall = localSharedPreferences.getBoolean("unknowncall", true);
            this.phonebook = localSharedPreferences.getBoolean("phonebook", true);`
            switch (paramInt) {
                default: return;

                Log.i("MyApp", "Silent mode");
                paramInt = 0;
                continue;
                Log.i("MyApp", "Vibrate mode");
                paramInt = 0;
                continue;
                Log.i("MyApp", "Normal mode");
            case 1:
            }
        }
        String str1 = paramString.substring(3);`

        Log.i("phonestate", paramInt + "," + str1);
        String str2;
        if ((this.phonebook) && (this.unknowncall)) {
            str2 = null;
            if (1 == paramInt)
                str2 = CallUtils.lookup(this.context, str1);
            if ((str2 == null) || (str2 == ""))
                str2 = str1;
            label224: if (str2 != null)
                break label393;
        }
        label393: String str4;
        String str5;
        for (String str6 = "";; str6 = str4 + " " + str2 + " " + str5) {
            Intent localIntent = new Intent(this.context, PhoneService.class);
            localIntent.putExtra(PhoneService.NAME_KEY, str6);
            nameOrNumber = str6;
            if (paramInt != 0)
                this.context.startService(localIntent);
            if (paramInt != 0)
                break;
            Utils.stopService(this.context, PhoneService.class);
            return;
            if ((this.phonebook) && (!this.unknowncall)) {
                str2 = null;
                if (1 != paramInt)`
                    break label224;
                str2 = CallUtils.lookup(this.context, str1);
                break label224;
            }
            boolean bool1 = this.phonebook;
            str2 = null;
            if (bool1)
                break label224;
            boolean bool2 = this.unknowncall;
            str2 = null;
            if (!bool2)
                break label224;
            String str3 = null;`
            if (1 == paramInt)
                str3 = CallUtils.lookup(this.context, str1);
            if (str3 == null) {
                str2 = str1;
                break label224;
            }
            str2 = null;
            break label224;
            str4 = LockStore.getMsgBefore(this.context);
            str5 = LockStore.getMsgAfter(this.context);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the whole code. The little snippet you posted isn't the problem.

Comment: Please post a better snapshot

Comment: Are the back tics ( ` ) also in the original code? They don't belong there!

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, but even with proper formatting this code would make my head hurt. What's with all the numbered variables and label jumps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Java doesn't allow declarations in labeled rows:

```
ExampleLabel: String exampleString; // this won't compile in my IDE
```

As far as I know, labels are made for loops (and conditions?) to break through more than one level in nested code.
They shouldn't be used as a replacement for gotos.

**Try to remove label393** - you are using it just once in a condition one row above, so it isn't necessary anyways. I think.

Besides your error: if you reach a point where your code won't compile, you don't know why and others are scratching their head when they look at it - it's time for redesigning and refactoring your code!

Start with useful names for your variables and avoid the use of labels (do you really need them? why?).

If you need help for labeled branching statements, have a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html